# Strip Price decimals when necessary

Tags: php, decimal, currency

This is more of an aesthetic problem, if I were to output two prices in PHP:

(the first being `123.45` and the second being `123.00`)

is there a way I can remove the `.00` from the second price when necessary (show it only appears as = `123`) but have it remain if there are numbers greater than 0 for a price (like the first price?).

Any help would be great, thanks!

TC

Answer (score 22, accepted):

what about...

```
$value = preg_replace('~\.0+$~','',$value);
```

Comment: I actually like this. Small and condensed, nice job.

Comment: Very nice, kudos on the simplicity!

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use (slow) regular expressions, you can use str_replace:

```
$value = str_replace('.00', '', $value);
```

note: I'm assuming you don't want to change '123.10' to '123.1', you only want to remove double zeros, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
function round2($decimal,$places = 2){
  $decimal = round($decimal,$places);
  if (floor($decimal)==$decimal)
    return (string)floor($decimal);
  return $decimal;
}
echo round2(123.45)."<br />".round2(123.00);
```

[Something like that?](http://www.ideone.com/ynaCU)